# Converting Iphone Screen to Ipad Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I created an Iphone app and I am trying to convert them to Ipad screens. I have a login page which was created for Iphone, I tried to change it to Ipad by changing Project Settings screen and changed the emulator. But the Login page looks weird on Ipad Emulator, controls are get stuck to the upper left corner. How can I fix it to look centered on Iphone and Ipad?

here is the screen on xcode

[image: xcode screen]

here is the screen on emulator

[image: emulator]

Comment: may be you not use different xib for iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the autolayout settings for each object.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2